# Bevel preventing me from seamlessly joining two modular pieces of geometry

Tags: geometry, bevel

I have two pieces of geometry that I want to join for a modular building this is my geometry without any bevel (the shaded black geometry)
[image: No bevel]

And this is with the bevel
[image: With bevel]

I know what the culprit is but have no idea how to fix it without making incompatible modular parts
It's due to where the geometry is connecting

Though I have added a real bevel with a 90 degree lip to stop beveling rather than shading and I have the same issue, but only on the overlapping part shown here for reference
[image: Join]
and here with the real bevel
[image: real bevel]

In this case it can also join to itself like so
[image: other join]

Any ideas on what I can do to prevent this?

Thanks,
Jamie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created small segments that fit between them, though I really don't like this solution! So if anyone has a better one please let me know!

[image]